# Do I need two /boot partitions for a dual boot system

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, grub

The current partitioning as shown in Gnome Disks is:

```
/dev/sda1 Linux Bootable 500mb
/dev/sda2 Linux LUKS Encryption 478gb (this is LVM)
Free Space 21gb
```

In /dev/sda2, there is /, swap and /home.

I want to install another distribution on the 21gb free space. It will share swap and home partitions with the current installation.

I will mount /home and swap as respective mountpoints and not format them. I will create / for the new distribution.

The question is what do I do with /boot? Do I use the existing one or a new one?

Also, do I need to install GRUB again? Where?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can share the `/boot` partition with multiple distributions, but it's not trivial. In order to avoid possible conflicts I'd only use ONE of them (typically the one with the most recent/up2date GRUB version) to "own"/configure/manage it. To prevent accidental damage I'm even mounting it readonly in the "non-owner" distributions (or not mounting it at all).

It may be a bit tricky to install the subsequent distributions without affecting the previous ones. Especially if handing over the `/boot` partition "ownership" to the newer installation. Personally I prefer to NOT use a separate `/boot` partition for the newer installation (temporarily making its `/` partition the bootable one) and manually "merging" it's `/boot` directory info into the shared `/boot` partition scheme *after* the installation. Updating a "non-owner" distribution also requires baby-sitting.

Always make backups copies of the `/boot` directories and the '/boot' partition along the way and have a bootable media ready for recovering the GRUB setup if something goes wrong.

Another approach is simply to not have separate `/boot` partitions for newer installation and simply chainload their `/` partitions (where their `/boot` directories reside) into the current GRUB scheme just like (older) Windows installations.

Be careful for possible issues with sharing the `swap` and `/home` partitions, here would be some Q&As you may want to go through for things to consider:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5656/are-there-any-side-effects-when-two-distros-share-a-swap-partition
- [Share the whole home directory between host and guest with Virtual Box](https://superuser.com/questions/922358/share-the-whole-home-directory-between-host-and-guest-with-virtual-box/922526#922526)

Comment: I then realized that doing all this will be much more troublesome than downloading a couple of 100 mbs of data! So, a separate /boot for the spearate OS

Comment: That might not be trivial/possible either if you only have one disk - at least in pre-EFI days you could only have a single bootable partition on one disk, so max one `/boot` partition per disk...

Answer (score 6):

Sharing a `/boot` partition between distributions is often possible, but is inadvisable, for a few reasons:

- Each OS will assume that it "owns" the partition, and so may try overwriting the others' files. This problem is most likely to be an issue for GRUB's `/boot/grub`, typically, but it can be an issue for other files, too, especially if your distributions are closely related. Ubuntu and Mint, for instance, will use the same kernel filenames.
- Boot loaders may become confused and unable to figure out which kernels go with which root (`/`) partitions. This can lead to boot failures and/or the need to manually tweak your boot configurations.
- If you ever want to delete or replace one distribution, the old one's kernels may be left behind, wasting space and creating additional confusion about which kernels go with which distributions.
- Some distributions may insist on erasing `/boot` before they'll install. (I'm not actually 100% positive of this, but I've definitely seen installers insist on erasing `/` before installing.) If your second distribution does this, it will of course wipe out the first distribution's kernels.
- With two distributions' kernels on one partition, that partition will need to be larger. This problem can of course be overcome by increasing the partition's size; it's more a matter of something you must consider rather than something that will definitely cause problems.

There's seldom any problem with creating an additional partition for `/boot`. Contrary to what Dan Cornilescu implied, the `/boot` partition does *not* need to be marked as bootable (under either BIOS or EFI). In fact, GRUB ignores the boot flag on MBR disks entirely, so you can boot with *no* "bootable" partition if you use GRUB *and* if your BIOS permits it. (Some BIOSes refuse to boot if there's no "bootable" partition.) Likewise, neither Linux nor GRUB cares if `/boot` is a primary partition or a logical partition, so you can use logical partitions for one or both of your `/boot` partitions, if necessary.